# Greedy search in prolog using heuristic value

Tags: prolog, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, shortest-path

I have a graph and a heuristic table, with a list connections and node values and also the cost (heuristic table).

Graph:
[image: Graphical representation]

Heuristic table:
[image: The cost of visiting node]

They're represented in prolog as follows.

```
s(a,b,2).
s(a,c,1).
s(b,e,4).
s(b,g,2).
s(c,d,1).
s(c,x,3).
s(x,g,1).

h(a,9)
h(b,3)
h(c,2)
h(d,8)
h(e,4)
h(g,0)
h(x,2)
```

My query, how do I perform a greedy search using the heuristic values h(a,9) to find the next node at each iteration.

I know how to use DFS to get shortest possible path and store that path using a list. I don't know how to take the heuristic values at each node into account to account for this in a greedy search - I do know that it expands the lowest h value node, to find it's next neighbor.

DFS:

```
depthfirstsearch(GoalN,Path,[GoalN|Path]) :- goal(GoalN).

depthfirstsearch(Node,Path,Solution) :- s(Node,NextNode,_), \+member(NextNode,Path), 
depthfirstsearch(NextNode,[Node|Path],Solution)
```

As I've search SO and the web (finding notes on how greedy search works) but nothing that explains how it actually works using prolog code. It explains how to do this in `java`, `C++`, etc. but I'm not using those languages.

Can anyone put me in the right direction? I read somewhere that findall could be used? But how do I combine the heuristic value to the node, for example Node "B" with a cost of 2, from A to B. Do I substitute the cost of 2, with the heuristic value/cost of 3. Please explain in more detail or direct me to another resource that would be beneficial right now?

I could maybe create a predicate to help find the next node at each iteration (using the heuristic value of course)?

Bear in mind I'm a beginner at prolog and trying out ways but struggling to piece it all together.

Update: This [link](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/AStarComparison.html) is where I find out most of the info on searches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to know what is a heuristic value and how it can be used in your searching algorithm.

**In my answer:**

- `n` is the node we want to reach
- `s` is the source node
- `h()` is the heuristic function. `h(n)` is an admissible [(?)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic)
  value, I prefer to think of it an **estimated cost** to reach `n`
  from source `s`. We call a heuristic good only if it does not safely
  over-estimate the cost.
- `w(a,b)` is the actual cost to go from `a` to `b`
- `g()` is a function giving **actual cost** to reach node `n` from `s`
  by summing up `w(a,b)` where both `a` and `b` are nodes in path from
  `n` to `s`.

**Now to answer your question, AFAIK you can use this heuristic in 2 ways:**

- As you have said, you can lazily ignore `w(a,b)` values and use
  `h(b)` values to sort the successor nodes (where `b` is any successor
  node) -- This is called **best first search** algorithm
- Another way would be to sort successor nodes based on value `h(b) +
  g(b)` (where `b` is any successor node) -- This is called **A*
  search** algorithm.

**Recommended Reading:**

- Stuart J Russell and Peter Norvig, ―Artificial Intelligence - A Modern Approach, Third Edition
- Ivan Brakto, ―Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence, Pearson Education, August 2011.

P.S. `findall` is the right thing to use in prolog to implement these 2 searches.